# Webdriver scripts hangs when java script error occurs or some content is loading for a while

Tags: webdriver

I have created selenium- webdriver scripts and it is running fine on FF and chrome but it is not working properly in IE-8.
Seems like application hangs at a certain page and it is waiting for a long time without giving any error.

I have tried different version of IE drivers from version `2.25.x.x to 2.28.x.x` - `OS: Windows XP`
Please let me know if there is any workaround for that.

Thanks in advance.

**Analysis:**

- I observed if application gets JavaScripts error or some content/images are loading at a certain page then only I got this issue.
- Also when I clear the browser cache and remove running IEDriverServer.exe from task manager then some time script executed successfully but it is not always true.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have set the [protected mode](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) to enabled or same for all security zones in your IE settings.

Comment: Thanks but I have already gone through the link provided by you but I am not seeing "protected mode" check box in IE-8.0.6001.18702. So dint do anything related to that. I am not sure if this could be the reason. Still looking for work around for that.

Comment: Well..that's strange that you do not see the checkbox at all.  I see it.. I am on IE8 as well..Where exactly did you check? I dont think that needs rights..

Comment: I have checked it on Tool-->Internet Option-->Security. And I have checked it to ther machine as well. i found it on IE9 but not in IE8.